# How to fix the error generated by repast.simphony.runtime.RepastMain?

Tags: java, repast-simphony

i have tried to programmatically start Repast-simphony using repast.simphony.runtime.RepastMain. So when i lunch it the saf.core.runtime.Boot class give this type error :

```
"ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] 14:43:38,880 saf.core.runtime.Boot - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at saf.core.runtime.Boot.init(Boot.java:79)
    at saf.core.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:246)
    at repast.simphony.runtime.RepastMain.main(RepastMain.java:43)
    at simmasto0.util.C_ChooseProtocol.actionPerformed(C_ChooseProtocol.java:123)
```

"

Would you like to help to find a solution for this issue?
Cordially!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String xmlFileName = "parameters_scenario_" + e.getActionCommand() + ".txt";
    splitRepastXmlConfigFiles(xmlFileName);
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() + " Protocol choosed");
    String[] args = new String[]{"C:\\Users\\sallmous\\`enter code here`Documents\\Workspace_Moussa\\SIMmasto_0\\SIMmasto_0.rs"};`enter code here`
    repast.simphony.runtime.RepastMain.main(args);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this error when the boot.properties file is not found. Boot first looks for the file in the scenario folder and if its not found there (which it typically isn't), it then defaults to the boot.properties file in the repast.simphony.runtime Eclipse plugin.

Note that more info about running Simphony from an external application can be found at: https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastFAQ/RepastFAQ.html#_running_models